# Iterate over multiple subdirectories to read.csv of a specific file

Tags: r, loops, lapply, read.csv

I have a folder with over 100 sub-folders that each contain a specific csv "cats.csv" that I need to read into R.

so far I've got:

```
parent_folder <- "path of parent files"
sub_folders <- list.dirs(parent_folder, recursive = TRUE)[-1]
cat_files <- dir(sub_folders, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE, pattern = "cats")
```

I've then tried variations of lapply and map to apply read.csv to load in all of the cat_files but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: *"doesn't seem to work"* is too vague. What happens? Errors/warnings? Mis-shaped data? You have a typo, `full.anmes=` should be `full.names=`, is that it?

Comment: Is the structure that there is a parent and then it has 100 folders in it direclty and then there is a cats.csv in each of those 100 folders or is the structure more nested.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yes, it has a parent folder, 100 folders within it, and a cats file in each of the 100

Answer (score 2):

```
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "cats.csv", recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)
```

then

```
lapply(setNames(nm=filelist), read.csv)
```

edit with thanks to r2evans below

Comment: It can often be helpful to keep the path with the data, use `lapply(setNames(nm=filelist), read.csv)`.

Comment: So when I go to lapply, it gives me Error in read.table(File - file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote : duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed

Answer (score 0):

We get the paths using Sys.glob (check that to be sure it is what you want) and then use Map to get a named list, DFs, of data.frames with the files' contents.

```
paths <- parent_folder |>
  file.path("*", "cats.csv") |>
  Sys.glob()

DFs <- Map(read.csv, paths)
```